# Create api filtering in js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, filtering, vuex

I need to filter data from an api which has different queries like brand, color, price, fuel and so on, for a car website.

[image]

The (fake) api is 
`https://api.example.com/api/v1/it/vehicles`

and with queries e.g.
`https://api.example.com/api/v1/it/vehicles?filter[transmission]=manual&filter[body]=van,suv`

I started by doing

```
import apiClient from '~/services/VehiclesService';

export default {
  fetchVehicles: async ({ commit }) => {
    const response = await apiClient.get('/vehicles').catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return error; // In order to get your Error returned from the Promise
    });
    commit('SET_VEHICLES', response.data.data);
  }
};
```

in vuejs

```
<v-list>
 <v-list-item>
   <v-list-item-content>
     <v-list-item-title>
       <v-checkbox class="ma-0 pa-0" v-model="c_v_b_a" :label="`Audi` + ' ' + c_number"></v-checkbox>
       <v-checkbox class="ma-0 pa-0" v-model="c_v_b_b" :label="`Bmw` + ' ' + '(11)'"></v-checkbox>
       <v-checkbox class="ma-0 pa-0" v-model="c_v_b_f" :label="`Fiat` + ' ' + '(13)'"></v-checkbox>
     </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>

computed: {
    filterByTerm(brand) {
      if (this.c_v_b_a) {
        this.c_v_b_b = false;
        this.c_v_b_f = false;
        return this.vehicles.filter(car => {
          return car.title.toLowerCase().includes("audi");
        });
      } else if (this.c_v_b_b) {
        this.c_v_b_a = false;
        this.c_v_b_f = false;
        return this.vehicles.filter(car => {
          return car.title.toLowerCase().includes("bmw");
        });
      } else if (this.c_v_b_f) {
        this.c_v_b_b = false;
        this.c_v_b_a = false;
        return this.vehicles.filter(car => {
          return car.title.toLowerCase().includes("fiat");
        });
      } else {
        return this.vehicles;
      }
    }

}
```

But this is not really my goal to filter the data in this way like above.
Is there a better way on how to filter the data with the api queries?

Any tips are welcome, thanks!

Comment: if you only can choose one option in the same time , why don't you use v-radio?

Comment: because you can choose between more then one brand

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but I will filter the car by doing this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="brands" value="audi"/>audi
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="brands" value="bmw"/>bmw
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="brands" value="fiat"/>fiat
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="priceRange" value="10000,20000"/>10000-20000
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="priceRange" value="20001,40000"/>20001-40000
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="priceRange" value="40001"/>>40000

 data: () => ({
   brands: [],
   vehicles: [
    { title: 'audi1', price: 10000},
    { title: 'audi2', price: 30000},
    { title: 'bmw1', price: 50000},
    { title: 'bmw2', price: 20000},
    { title: 'fiat1', price: 20000},
    { title: 'fiat2', price: 40000},
   ]
 }),

 computed: {
  filterByTerm() {
     return this.vehicles.filter(car => {
       return this.brands.filter(brand => {
        if (car.title.toLowerCase().includes(brand)) {
          return this.priceRange.filter(priceRange => {
            const priceArr = priceRange.split(',')
            const priceStart = priceArr[0]
            const priceEnd = priceArr[1] ? priceArr[1] : Infinity
            return car.price >= parseInt(priceArr[0]) && car.price <= priceEnd
          }).length > 0 || this.priceRange.length === 0
        }
        return false
       }).length > 0
     });
  }
 }
```

Comment: and how can I use mutliply filters like price and brand

Comment: @masterOne I just edited my answer, but I think you'd better to figure out the logic that you want.